# How to get the responses of an API call (shopify)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, shopify

I've been using rails for about a week and have found numerous good tutorials but haven't found any info for my current problem.
I have a webshop running and can access it via the shopify console:

```
      ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(674469828)
      -> will return the customer with the id 674469828
```

If I use the same code in my rails app nothing happens. I would like to get the error message of this API call and have no idea how to do this. I mean I'm sending a POST request to the service and am getting a response (HTTP/1.1 200 OK for example).
How can I "catch" the http response in my code? How can I display the response header? I could use simple http requests and get the responses easily but if there's an API, why not use it.
I'd be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set up your app with API credentials etc, you can "catch" the response by assigning it to a variable, like so:

```
customer = ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(674469828)
# now we can play around with the customer object

customer.name # => "Jimmy"
```

If this doesn't help / is missing the point, please post a specific error message or server output that you are getting along with the specific request you made.

Comment: That's what I thought. I was trying cust = ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(self.global_id)
Later on I tried to delete the user with cust.destroy and nothing happened. I don't know why since the exact same code is working in the console. Was hoping to get the error message somehow

Comment: What is `self`? Where is the code (model, controller, what?) and how is it being used? Can you post the exact relevant snippet and context in your question? You should be able to see the response to your request in the server console (the tab where you typed `rails s`) when this code is run.

Comment: I am creating requests in my application. "Create", "Update" and "Delete". I am putting in the info I need in a form and submit the data and pass it to my model "request". There I have a switch case statement (for now) and make the API call with the given data. I can create users, but I cannot find any of them even though I can via the shopify console. In the server console I only get the OK status for submitting the form, not for the actual response from the API.

Comment: Welp, this is rather embarrassing. I've just added flash[:error] = @request.errors.full_messages.join(' ') to see possible errors during creation. Suddenly "Email is not valid" popped up. I've forgotten about the validation method I wrote to accept valid emails in the form and of course it didn't allow me to post a form with an empty email. The validation was not allowing me to POST my request, I'm ashamed of myself. Thanks for your time anyway